# jQuery's wysiwyg validation problem

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery's wysiwyg plugin on one of the pages. When the form get's posted I have checked if there is some content present in the editor. If the editor is blan then I have shown the message to enter some content in the wysiwyg editor. However this validation is not getting applied since when I alert the value of wysiwyg edior it shows me `"<P></P>"` or `"<P>&nbsp;</P>"` so the condition to check the balnk value of editor ($("#wysiwyg").val() == "") is not getting applied.

Even if the `"<P></P>"` or `"<P>&nbsp;</P>"` content is replaced then also it giving different results in Mozilla & IE7.

Comment: What plugin are you exactly using? There are a ton of wysiwyg plugins for jQuery out there.

Comment: I am using WYSIWYG - jQuery plugin 0.6

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a `getContent()` method avalaible, can you try that one?